# Importing Factor code without putting it in the work directory?

Tags: import, include, require, factor-lang

I like version controlling my code. It would be a pain to copy every Factor file from my git over to Factor's work directory and back.

Does Factor have an import command that works like Ruby's `require`, one that looks in the current directory for source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to write a macro that does this. Add the following to `~/.factor-rc`:

```
! INCLUDING macro that imports source code files in the current directory

USING: kernel vocabs.loader parser sequences lexer vocabs.parser ;
IN: syntax

: include-vocab ( vocab -- ) dup ".factor" append parse-file append use-vocab ;

SYNTAX: INCLUDING: ";" [ include-vocab ] each-token ;
```

Which you can use like this (see [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptedMain#Factor)).

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor

INCLUDING: scriptedmain ;
USING: io math.parser ;
IN: test

: main ( -- ) meaning-of-life "Test: The meaning of life is " write number>string print ;

MAIN: main
```